# How to solve the totalsum issue while using ng-hide in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. I am trying to `hide` a value and get the proper `totalsum` value too..[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XEhaAQT1dJky2juoxsTb?p=preview)   if `inclusive` is `checked or true` the `exclusive`is false so the value should need to hide, so i have used `ng-hide`, the value also hidden. but the total sum value is displaying like hidden exclusive value too, so what i'm expecting  if some of value is hidden the  totalsum value must to be calculate rest of the values only..**For Example**:- if `inclusive` is true the `exclusive` value is `hidden` then the exclusive totalsum value should be `388` not like `499`....... please look at the plunker and help me for the same thanks...

**Controller:-** For Exclusive Totalsum functionality:-

```
.filter('totalSumPriceQty', function () {
    return function (data, key1, key2) {        
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
            return 0;

        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) - parseInt(v[key2])/100);
        });
        return sum;
    }
})

    .filter('totalSumPriceQtytwo', function () {
       return function (data, key1, key2) {        
         if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
            return 0;
              var sum = 0;
                angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
                  sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) * parseInt(v[key2])/100);
             });
        return sum;
       }
    })
```

**My HTML:-**

```
<td ><p ng-hide="mani.service_tax==false">{{(mani.invoice_quantity - mani.invoice_value_fob/100)}}</p></td>

    <td ><p ng-hide="mani.exclusive==false">{{(mani.invoice_quantity * mani.invoice_value_fob/100)}}</p></td>
```

**Totalsum Html:-**

```
<td>{{resultValue | totalSumPriceQty:'invoice_quantity':'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>

  <td>{{resultValue | totalSumPriceQtytwo:'invoice_quantity':'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>
```

I have created Plunker for reference:- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XEhaAQT1dJky2juoxsTb?p=preview)

**One more Example:-**

Here one inclusive transaction is true another one is false...we have used ng-hide to hide the false value...the totalsum need to be calculate true value only like answer will be `34`..... not like `127` pls help us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each of the filters, add the same logic to exclude the data that you use to hide

```
filter('totalSumPriceQty', function () {
    return function (data, key1, key2) {        
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
            return 0;

        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
          if(v.service_tax){
            sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) - parseInt(v[key2])/100);
          }
        });
        return sum;
    }
})

filter('totalSumPriceQtytwo', function () {
    return function (data, key1, key2) {        
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
            return 0;

        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
          if(v.exclusive){
            sum = sum + (parseInt(v[key1]) * parseInt(v[key2])/100);
          }
        });
        return sum;
    }
})
```

see forked [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/epGdSetcRDRlO5RQFX6U?p=preview)